# PNG Images distorted muddy in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, png

I'm building a site that is almost complete. The problem I am having is with IE7 and displaying images that look very distorted/muddy.

First how it looks in all the other browsers I tested, including IE8.

Removed due to link limit on new accounts

And then the muddy one from IE7

[Muddy/Distorted Image](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/mxygy)

After doing some googling it looks like it has to do with the pixel transparency in PNG images on IE7.

First I tried setting a solid background color in the actual background file. This did not work as the image was still very muddy and distorted.

Next I tried specifying a fixed width and height but still the same result. Not sure what else to try at this point.

Any suggestions I am willing to try.

Here is the code pertaining to the element.

```
.feature {
    padding-top:10px;
    border-top:solid 1px #ccc;
    width:440px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding-bottom:5px;
}
.featureimg {
    float:left;
    width:190px;
}
.featureimg img {
    max-height:90px;
    max-width:190px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.featuretext {
    float:right;
    text-align:left;
    width:250px;
}
<div class="feature">
    <div class="featureimg">
        <img src="images/certipur.png" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="featuretext">
        <div class="featurehead red">
            Sealed with comfort and confidence
        </div>
        <p>
            TEXT BLOCK
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="clear">
    </div>
 </div>
```

Here is the link to original file https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3fuV.jpg

Comment: can you upload your png to a site like imgur so we can attempt to re-create your problem?

Comment: Here you go. http://imgur.com/z2SoV. Converting to a jpeg did not work either.

Comment: Can't duplicate the issue. Have you tried on other machines?

Comment: Your image has already been matted, or whatever they call it when the bit of the background colour is on the edge. This image was created expecting to be on a white/light background. Meaning, you don't need PNG's alpha transparency if that's really the problem. Index that thing and serve as an 8-bit PNG. So, simple gif-like transparency. The filesize will be much smaller too. Your screenshot looks to me like things I've seen when browsers try to resize images and windows, but I've never seen that from alpha transparency.

Comment: Tried all the above examples given by @stommepoes to no avail. If you guys can't recreate it maybe it is just my machine. It is running inside of a VM. I don't have another machine to try it on just yet but will see if I can reproduce it elsewhere. Funny thing is IE6 displays it just fine.

Comment: The image does look resized.  Perhaps your IE7 is zoomed out?

Answer (score 0):

In case you still care: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A54K2.jpg

I tried using BrowserStack.com to check for the image using IE7 and it didn't look muddy at all. I guess it your VM display settings but i think it shows up perfectly fine. :)